# How to fix an error in code which Dynamically Transfer data in All Google Sheets based on Filter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Sheet for recording my stock. I am trying to automate everything. There are multiple sheets with stock names. I have one sheet title "History1" where I input data manually and I build the following code to segregate all the data in the respective sheets. Here is the link of Sheet [Trade Binance Google Sheet Tracker](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KD_qFT6J6ife72OhQRzr0pHSiyyRNA3X8KCDTc2A-iE/edit#gid=1709254924)

I have written the following script but it is giving me errors and does not work correctly.

```
  function split_history() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const hsh = ss.getSheetByName("History1");
  const hvs = hsh.getRange(2,1,hsh.getLastRow() -1,9).getValues();
  const shts = ss.getSheets();
  const excl  = ["Summary","History1","Main Menu"];
  shts.forEach(s => {
    let oA = [];
    if(!~excl.indexOf(s.getName())) {
      hvs.forEach(r => {
        if(s.getName() == r[0]) {
          oA.push(r.slice(0,8));
        }
      });
      s.getRange(getColumnHeight(1,s,ss) + 1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
    }
  });
}
```

It is giving me the following error. any suggestion or correction, please. Thanks
[image]

Comment: the code on the screenshot looks different, please put them in sync so that they can be analyzed. also why do you wave the bitwise not `~` operator in your `if` statement?

Comment: Trying to reproduce this issue I have gotten an error from the macros.gs file. Can you provide the exact changes on the code in order to test it?

Answer (score 0):

the `vals` or `oA` (depending on which code you look at, listing or the screenshot) array is empty, this is what the message is about.
You must find out why is it empty.